# Como obter valor de TempData com List<object>?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net

Segue código:

```
List<object> list = new List<object>
{
    "abc",      // string
    1,          // int
    true        // bool
};

TempData["ID"] = list;
```

O código a seguir não consigo obter valor:

```
var data = TempData["ID"];

var test1 = data[0];  //<---- Problema: Não é possível aplicar a indexação com [] a uma expressão do tipo "object"
```

Alguma solução ou existe outra forma mais fácil ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como o valor de cada alemento de `TempData` é do tipo `object` realmente não há indexador para ele. Teria que fazer um *cast*  para `List<object>` para poder de fato ter uma lista em mãos e aí acessar seus elementos.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Program {
    public static void Main() {
        var list = new List<object> {
            "abc",      // string
            1,          // int
            true        // bool
        };
        var TempData = new Dictionary<string, object>(); //só pra poder testar aqui
        TempData["ID"] = list;
        var data = TempData["ID"];
        var test1 = ((List<object>)data)[0];
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/yPAl17). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/LqwHtb). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/bigown/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/ASP.NET/TempDataMember.cs).

Mas vou dizer que isto parece ser uma bela gambiarra. Quase toda vez que alguém cria lista com `objects`, especialmente se ela terá poucos elementos, provavelmente está fazendo algo errado. Se precisa disto provavelmente precisa de uma classe ou tupla e não uma lista. Isto fica mais claro com os comentários usados.

Já estou na dúvida se deveria usar o `TempData`.

Comment: Porque a ideia é enviar valores de ActionResult para outro ActionResult sem usar parâmetro. Então seria tipo: TempData ?

Comment: Tem casos que sim, mas tem casos que é melhor fazer uma *ViewModel*, e parece ser o seu caso, apesar de ter postado um exemplo muito abstrato.